# Save file from file-picker for later use (without picking again)

Tags: java, android

I need to let user choose a file(certificate `.pem` file) from internal storage. This is used to access the server but when app is closed and reopened it would be annoying to choose cert every time. What I want to do is save this file for later use, how can that be done? If possible I would want to copy said cert file to application raw/assets folder.
Here's how I get the file:

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> sARL = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Context context = getmInstanceActivity();
            Intent data = result.getData();
        }
    }
});

public void openFileDialog( View view){
Intent data = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
data.setType("*/*");
data = Intent.createChooser(data, "Choose file");
sARL.launch(data);
}
```

Right now I use the file, but this is hard coded to raw folder, which contains the cert for now. If possible, I would like to leave this part of the code as is.

```
InputStream certificateChainAsInputStream = MainActivity.getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certFile);
```

Any ideas how to save this selected file so you don't have to do it manually every time would be a great help.

Comment: You have to take permanent uri permission in onActivityResult in order to use an uri later.

Comment: `Any ideas how to save this selected file ` ? You will not save that file. As then you would have a copy. You only have to remember which file it is. Indeed: save Uri.toString() to shared preferences.

Comment: How can I gain permanent uri permission? Right now I loose this permission when application is closed.

Comment: You should take persistable uri permission was the hint. Now did you google for it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions

Comment: After adding flags to the Intent (    Intent data = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    data.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    data.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);) I still continue to get the error. And yes, I did google it.

Comment: You should not add those flags to your intent. Better read the link OneCricketeer gave you as there you see what to do. `contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)`

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked, `raw/assets` is considered read-only and is a build-time file location. Rather than copy anything, you can [reference the file's URI (absolute file path) after choosing](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#perform-operations), then save that as a String in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).

However, you will need to catch exceptions if the saved file-path is renamed or moved and have the app re-prompt to choose that file, as well as handle Intent/URI permission requests, as indicated by the docs.

Comment: I seem to get error "Permission Denial: opening provider... requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs" . I saved uri to SP like this : editor.putString("Certificate", String.valueOf(uri)); and later retrieved it like this: uri = Uri.parse(sharedPreferences.getString("Certificate", ""));                                                                                     EDIT: Error is thrown with this line: InputStream trustedCertificateAsInputStream = MainActivity.getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

Comment: `String.valueOf(uri)` Better: `uri.toString()`.

Comment: `For Internal Storage, you can reference a file URI (` That already makes no sense when using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Sorry.

Comment: I have thes permissions in place already:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>.                                          What I found on the internet is that this permission can't be regained (https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util/issues/118) so only option would be to copy the file to somewhere accessible.

Comment: @blackapps Feel free to add your own answer. I was only referring how to persist the result from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Not answering how to actually read that file within the app

Comment: Nothing in your answer would persist the result of ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. What has to be done instead i wrote in another comment.

Comment: @blackapps The code in the question already has `intent.getData()` [which has the URI](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#perform-operations). I'm not sure what you're telling me

Comment: It has the uri. It does not have permanent uri permission. The question was how to get a permanent uri permission.

Comment: @blackapps And that is a separate question from the OP which was how to persist the value of the chosen file.